# How to convert Camel case string to snake case

Tags: string, go

**I have  a string**

```
str := "IGotInternAtGeeksForGeeks"
```

**I try to convert it in to**

`str = "i_got_intern_at_geeks_for_geeks"`

Comment: Despite the answer, we are not here to do your work for you. You must show your attempt.

Comment: Ok  @flimzy...I am try to convert such camel string to snak....it's work . But thanks for you point.

Comment: I know what you're trying to do. You said that in your question. My point is, questions are expected to show a best effort, including code.

Comment: Great question +1. The preferred Go term is MixedCaps or mixedCaps not CamelCase. See https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#mixed-caps.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this,

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "regexp"
)

var matchFirstCap = regexp.MustCompile("(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)")
var matchAllCap   = regexp.MustCompile("([a-z0-9])([A-Z])")

func ToSnakeCase(str string) string {
    snake := matchFirstCap.ReplaceAllString(str, "${1}_${2}")
    snake  = matchAllCap.ReplaceAllString(snake, "${1}_${2}")
    return strings.ToLower(snake)
}
```

Run:

```
func main() {   
    fmt.Println(ToSnakeCase("IGotInternAtGeeksForGeeks"))
}
```

Output:

```
i_got_intern_at_geeks_for_geeks
```

**NOTE:**  This will not work for many non-English languages.

Comment: Do you happen to know the reason the first capital letter is treated differently from the others?

Comment: I double the question by @JHS The only difference I found is if symbol preceding first capital letter is non alphanumeric, e.g. "$Test" will become "$_test" only with first expression

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old post but, I've create a package named [gobeam/Stringy](https://github.com/gobeam/Stringy) You can easily convert camel case string to snake case and kebab case and vice versa. Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    stringy "github.com/gobeam/Stringy"
)

func main() {
    str := stringy.New("HelloGuysHowAreYou?")
    snakeStr := str.SnakeCase("?", "")
    fmt.Println(snakeStr.ToLower()) // hello_guys_how_are_you
    fmt.Println(snakeStr.ToUpper()) // HELLO_GUYS_HOW_ARE_YOU
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert to sentence case? e.g. `CamelCase` to `Camel case`?

Answer (score 5):

Without reguar expression version.

Letters only, because the use case is struct field db tag. Feel free to modify it for other use cases.

```
func ToSnake(camel string) (snake string) {
    var b strings.Builder
    diff := 'a' - 'A'
    l := len(camel)
    for i, v := range camel {
        // A is 65, a is 97
        if v >= 'a' {
            b.WriteRune(v)
            continue
        }
        // v is capital letter here
        // irregard first letter
        // add underscore if last letter is capital letter
        // add underscore when previous letter is lowercase
        // add underscore when next letter is lowercase
        if (i != 0 || i == l-1) && ( // head and tail
            (i > 0 && rune(camel[i-1]) >= 'a') || // pre
                (i < l-1 && rune(camel[i+1]) >= 'a')) { //next
            b.WriteRune('_')
        }
        b.WriteRune(v + diff)
    }
    return b.String()
}

// here is the test
func TestToSnake(t *testing.T) {
    input := "MyLIFEIsAwesomE"
    want := "my_life_is_awesom_e"
    if got := ToSnake(input); got != want {
        t.Errorf("ToSnake(%v) = %v, want %v", input, got, want)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Faster and simpler version:

```
import "bytes"

func SnakeCase(camel string) string {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    for _, c := range camel {
        if 'A' <= c && c <= 'Z' {
            // just convert [A-Z] to _[a-z]
            if buf.Len() > 0 {
                buf.WriteRune('_')
            }
            bytes.WriteRune(c - 'A' + 'a')
        } else {
            bytes.WriteRune(c)
        }
    }
    return buf.String()
}
```

Known bugs: 
 1. no-ascii
 2. reversed upper abbreviate word, eg. baseURL will be ugly `base_u_r_l`, but not `base_url`, consider use white list to filter.

Answer (score 0):

wrapped it into a package

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/buxizhizhoum/inflection"
)

func example () {
    // to convert a string to underscore
    res := inflection.Underscore("aA")
    // will return a_a
    fmt.Println(res)
    // to convert a string to camelize
    // will return AA
    fmt.Println(inflection.Camelize("a_a", true))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unicode compatible version:

```
pattern := regexp.MustCompile("(\\p{Lu}+\\P{Lu}*)")
s = pattern.ReplaceAllString(s, "${1}_")
s, _ = strings.CutSuffix(strings.ToLower(s), "_")
```

`\p{Lu}` matches all charaters in the unicode class for uppercase letters ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Unicode_character_class_escape))

Answer (score 0):

This one I used recently, for me, it's much simpler and faster.

```
import "strings"

func ToSnakeCase(s string) string {
    var result string

    for i, v := range s {
        if i > 0 && v >= 'A' && v <= 'Z' {
            result += "_"
        }

        result += string(v)
    }

    return strings.ToLower(result)
}
```

Here is playground link: https://go.dev/play/p/xY-hKz1BSPJ